# Regex Not Matching The First Alternative It Should

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a regex that I use to clean up account names, and with the new year I have to adjust it to capture a new version of an account name that another team is using. However, I'm having a hard time understanding why simply adding another alternative isn't working.

Here's what I'm using:

`^.*\b((?i)foxtrot movie|whiskey|whiskeyfoxtrotmovie)\b.*$`

This works wonderfully for the other versions of the account name in the data, which is primarily "Foxtrot Movie". But now I want it to capture "Whiskey Foxtrot Movie" and "Foxtrot Movie".

For clarification, both are in the column that this regex goes through. I want the whole string captured when either of these appears. I never want the "Whiskey" to not be captured, and "Whiskey Foxtrot Movie" and "Foxtrot Movie" are different lines among a bunch of other account names.

I know Regex is eager, and so to encourage matching with the larger string first I adjusted the expression within the boundary to be 
`\b((?i)whiskeyfoxtrotmovie|whiskey foxtrot movie|whiskey|foxtrot movie)\b`, yet it's only capturing "Foxtrot Movie" even for the longer string. I can't figure out why it doesn't match with the second alternative to capture "Whiskey Foxtrot Movie"

`(whiskey)? foxtrot movie` results in the same error. 
Moving the order around doesn't seem to help either. Encasing each alternative in `()` also fails me.

I'm still new at this, so maybe there's something I don't understand about boundaries? But this does work as long as I don't have `whiskey foxtrot movie` and `foxtrot movie` in the expression at the same time. Maybe spaces?

Any insight is welcome.

Comment: Use just `(?i)\b(whiskeyfoxtrotmovie|whiskey foxtrot movie|whiskey|foxtrot movie)\b`. Do not use `.*` and anchors. If you must match the whole string, replace the frst `.*` with `.*?`.

Comment: Show the failing code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! Removing the anchors worked. For my own knowledge, is there a reason why they weren't a problem in my original code, but where when I wanted to add the new alternative?

Comment: I understand your problem was in the first greedy `.*`, the alternatives were tried when the most of the leftmost text was already grabbed with the first `.*`. So, `(?i)\b(whiskeyfoxtrotmovie|whiskey foxtrot movie|whiskey|foxtrot movie)\b` itself should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first greedy `.*`, the alternatives are tried when the most of the leftmost text is already grabbed with the first `.*`.

If you must match the whole string, replace the frst `.*` with `.*?`, but it makes more sense to use the method that allows partial matches and just use

```
(?i)\b(whiskeyfoxtrotmovie|whiskey foxtrot movie|whiskey|foxtrot movie)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bCz5G8/1).

That is, remove `^` and `$` anchors and the enclosing `.*` patterns.